# Qt add points one by one with QThread or QTimer?

Tags: qt

I want to make a program in Qt to add points one by one, not all at once. To do that, I need to use QThread, or I can just use QTimer?

Comment: can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: I did only to add points all at once..

Comment: What are "points"? How many and why not "all at once"?

Answer (score 0):

it can be done using `QTimer` and if it is time dependent (like every 1 second) then its the way to go. just create the timer, connect its `timeout` signal to your `slot` and it should work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You need create some class, inherited from `QObject`:

```
class QTimer;
class QList;

class Test_Timer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Test_Timer(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Test_Timer();

private:
    QList<QPoint> *lst;
    QTimer *timer;

public slots:
    void addPoint();
};
```

Ok, now we have `timer` variable for `QTimer` events, `lst` for store `QPoint` and `addPoint()` slot for handling your timer event.

At constructor we initialize members of class, connect timer's slot with current class slot and start timer with period 500ms:

```
Test_Timer::Test_Timer(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    lst = new QList<QPoint>;
    timer = new QTimer;

    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(addPoint()));

    timer->start(500);
}
```

Slot for adding points may look something like this:

```
void Test_Timer::addPoint()
{
    static int number = 0;

    if (lst->size() < 10) {
        lst->append(QPoint(0, number++));
        qDebug() << lst->size();
    } else {
        timer->stop();
        deleteLater();
    }
}
```

After all don't remember free resources:

```
Test_Timer::~Test_Timer()
{
    lst->clear();
    delete lst;

    if (timer->isActive())
        timer->stop();
    delete timer;
}
```

I think this example will be helpful for you.

Comment: This is a wonderful attempt at guesswork, but really, you shouldn't encourage the posters who ask such vague questions.